# Is there a function in NCurses to get the location of a window?

Tags: c++, linux, window, ncurses

When creating a window using NCurses and [`newwin()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/newwin), the first two parameters are to the top left coordinates of the window. To find the size of a window, I can use [`getmaxyx()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getmaxyx). Can I do the same thing for the (current) top left coordinates of a window? I could not find a similar function in the man pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information is in the same manual page:

- [`getyx`,  `getparyx`,  **`getbegyx`**,  `getmaxyx`  -  get curses cursor and window
     coordinates](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getyx.3x.html)

> Like  **`getyx`**,  the **`getbegyx`** and **`getmaxyx`** macros store the ***current beginning coordinates*** and size of the specified window.